# Unpermitted parameters in a simple rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I started my application using scaffold generating:

```
rails g scaffold Category title

rails g scaffold Product category:references title

rake db:migrate
```

I started the server and created a new category and then I wanted to add a new product to this category using it's `id` which is `1` but when I checked the log:

```
Started POST "/products" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-01 09:28:16 +0430
Processing by ProductsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"dd7tvD/DrXf1SiAnCR6ZUvtwQzVuy39HG4A9dmo7Gms=", "product"=>{"category"=>"1", "title"=>"Rails"}, "commit"=>"Create Product"}
Unpermitted parameters: category
```

And there is `category_id` in permitted parameters of product contorller:

```
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:category_id, :title)
end
```

**EDIT**:

Models:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Product form:

```
<%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>
  <% if @product.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this product from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @product.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :catagory %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :catagory %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Could you please help me? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post you related models.. It will help to confirm associations

Comment: You should be adding related association in `Category` model also

Comment: Add `has_many :products` to your `category.rb` model

Comment: @Pavan As I know 'has_many :products' just adds some functionality to Category model and nothing to do with 'Unpermitted parameters: category'. I tested and it's not working.

Comment: @RAJ... the same as Pavan

Comment: @ThePianist You have mentioned that `product` belongs_to `category`. Try removing this statement then try, if you don't want to have both ways relation

Comment: Can you post your `form code`?

Comment: @Pavan Good point! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `form_for` tag, you must have `category_id` field, instead of `category` field (I'm not sure why you want to ask `category_id` from user).

```
<%= f.label :catagory_id %><br>
<%= f.text_field :catagory_id %>
```

Apart of the answer, association between `products` and `category` is not proper. You are missing `has_many`.

Your `category` model should looks like:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end
```

Comment: Good.I'm too late to answer.

Comment: There is no early or late. we are here to get and give help.. :) Good work bro

Comment: Thanks. worked! But I think this is a bug in scaffold command. What do you think?

Comment: No, your scaffold commands are just fine... there was typo or something else